# Buscar caracteres MYSQL WORKBENCH

Tags: mysql-workbench

Tengo una duda, debo hacer una consulta que me traigan los números del medio que contengan 0,8 o 5.

Use el comando `REGEXP` pero no me ha resultado. Me aparece como null, en sql server me funciono perfectamente pero con LIKE

```
SELECT autor_id
FROM autores
WHERE autor_id REGEXP '____[0,5,8]%';
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *los números del medio*?

Comment: por ej 897-08-12 el 0 y 8 serian los del medio, no se como hacer esa consulta en mysql

Comment: Si son valores **siempre con el formato `999-00-99`** y sólo te interesa verificar los que están en `00`, entonces la expresión adecuada sería esta: `REGEXP  '....[0,5,8]...$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, quieres aquellas columnas que contengan `0`, `5` u `8` a partir del cuarto carácter.

En `REGEXP`de MySQL el punto (`.`) representa un carácter simple. Entonces, de este modo debería funcionar:

```
SELECT autor_id
FROM autores
WHERE autor_id REGEXP  '....[0,5,8]$';
```

Ahí buscará `0, 5 u 8` a partir del cuarto carácter (por eso los cuatro `.`).

Ver más detalles [aquí](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s08.html).

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha resultado!